# SQLAlchemy mismatches column with orm query

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, pytest

I have a simple relationship of a Subscription and Subscriber tables/models in a Flask app in which I'm using SQLAlchemy to query a SQLite database locally during development.

A Subscription has a relationship to a Subscriber through a `subscriber_id` field defined as follows:

```py
subscriber_id = Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('subscriber.id'))
```

Both objects have a field defined as `String(36)` in which I'm writing a UUID4 string into when they are created in the database. They are `subscription_id` and `subscriber_id`, respectively, like this:

```py
@dataclass
class Subscription(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'subscription'

    subscription: str
    subscriber: str

    id = Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subscription_id = Column(
        db.String(36),
        default=generate_uuid,  # a function that returns a uuid4
        unique=True
    )
    subscriber_id = Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('subscriber.id'))
```

---

During test execution using PyTest I'm facing a weird behavior in which the `subscriber_id` of a `Subscription` instance is returning not the integer, as defined in the class, but a UUID.

The test runs a method that queries the subscriber, and then attempts to get its subscriptions:

```py
subscriber = Subscriber.query.filter(
    Subscriber.subscriber_id == subscriber_id
).first()

assert subscriber is not None

subscriptions = Subscription.query.filter(
    Subscription.subscriber_id == subscriber_id
).all()
```

`subscriber_id` is `1` during execution, and the subscriber is retrieved from the database.

The second query, however, does not work, even though `subscriber_id` is a foreign key to the subscriber's `id`.

If I replace the second query with another without filter, it works. But then I see this issue, where the `subscriber_id` returned is not an integer, but a UUID:

```py
raise Exception(Subscription.query.first().subscriber_id)
```

```
        subscriptions = Subscription.query.filter(
            Subscription.subscriber_id == subscriber_id
        ).all()
    
>       raise Exception(Subscription.query.first().subscriber_id)
E       Exception: 59ebfdd6-1cbc-4748-94e1-955ef55c380c
```

Is there a special behavior of SQLAlchemy that I am not taking into account here? A naming convention for tables/fields, perhaps?

Comment: `Subscription.id` is already the primary key. What is the purpose of the candidate key `Subscription.subscription_id` ?

Comment: also, check your work. `subscriber_id` won't return a uuid, but `subscription_id` will. There's no naming convention in play here.

Comment: @GordThompson the purpose is not to show the actual ID in the request URI or body, since it is an API. It is kind of an alternative ID. I plan to use the actual `id` in internal calls though. I'll update the original post with more info.

Comment: Oh wait, this is SQLite. Have you [explicitly enabled foreign key support](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support)?

Comment: @GordThompson that is really weird. When enabling foreign key support explicitly, I get an IntegrityException.

Comment: Good lord, I figured it out. Not enabling foreign keys apparently made possible to assign other data types to the foreign keys fields. After enabling foreign keys I saw that the code failed on another part, while creating the related record between the two tables (that is: the subscription). The code was creating the record with the UUIDs in place of the actual `id`s as foreign keys.

Comment: @GordThompson thank you so much for the help. Please feel free to provide an answer so I can mark this as solved! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wonderful as SQLite is, it has two features that make it quite "different" from most other SQL implementations:

1. SQLite does not strictly enforce column types, it only recognizes column ["affinities"](https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html#flexible_typing). Therefore it is possible to declare a column as `INT`, insert a string (like the string representation of a UUID) into it, and SQLite won't necessarily raise an error.
2. SQLite accepts foreign key constraint declarations but it [ignores them by default](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html). That can lead to confusion when working with SQLite and expecting foreign keys to "just work".

Both of these behaviours came into play for this issue. A coding error was inserting (UUID) strings into a column that was intended to be integer, and the lack of enforcement of foreign key constraints caused that error to go unnoticed.

Moral: Use SQLite and appreciate it for what it can offer, but also be aware of its particular "personality" (just like any other SQL dialect).